# Callback method is not working for Google Drive API Login in Safari (IOS 6 and lower versions)

Tags: javascript, safari, callback, google-drive-api

Callback method is not get called after successful Login to the Google in Safari browser (IOS 6 and lower versions). But it's working perfect for all other Desktop browsers and android devices. It is even working perfect in Safari IOS 7. But I couldn't able to trace out why it's not get called after the successful login process. After Login the popup window gets closed, but nothing is happened in the main window (callback method is not called by the browser).

Here is my code:

```
var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
if(token)               
driveCallBack();
 else 
    this._doAuth(false, function() { driveCallBack(); }.bind(this));
```

Sample Code: https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054

Here I'm not using the Google Drive File Picker, instead of that I'm listing the files and folders in my application only.

Please get me some solution for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue when tried the following code:

```
var driveLogInCallBackCheck = setInterval(function () {
         var request =gapi.auth.getToken()

         if(request)
         {
           //Login successful Code here..
           window.clearInterval(driveLogInCallBackCheck);
         }
        }, 250);
```

Hope it may help someone facing the same issue.